# ias infinite scroll reinitialize pagination (and content) after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination, infinite-scroll

this is my code:

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
            var ias = $.ias({
                container: ".el-prod",
                item: ".item-prod",
                pagination: "#pagination",
                next: ".next",
                history: false
            });
            ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension());
            ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({ html: '<div class="ias-noneleft"><em><%=WebApp.Translate("no more product!") %></em></div>' }));

  $("#fil-el").submit(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: '/ajax/load_product.aspx',
                data: $("#fil-el").serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                 //new pagination and list of item sorting or filtered
                    $("#pagination").replaceWith(data.pag);
                    $(".el-prod"").html(data.prodotti);
                    ias.reinitialize();
                }
            });
        });

    });
```

How can I reinitialize ias plugin with new pagination?

ias.reinitialize() not working!
"Reinitializes Infinite AJAX Scroll after a DOM update. DOM updates could be made by page updates via AJAX, like changing the sorting of a list, or filtering a result."

Comment: Try with `jQuery.ias().initialize();`.

Comment: it doesn't work :(
Continue reading the old pagination and not the new one that I provide